# Authorization Web Asp.Net Core JWT , Angular 8

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

can some please point where the issue is.
the problem that i encounter is i have a controller that i added an attribute Authorize. So, when i try to access the actionResult GETDATA  it says unable to find the action. but if remove the attribute Authorize, it's working as expected.
So everytime i make a request i add a jwt token on the header.
Here are codes:

```
**Angular 8 HttpInterceptor**

    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    //if (currentUser && currentUser.authData) {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.Token) {
      debugger;
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.Token}`,
          CurrentTabID: `${currentUser.CurrentTabID}`
        }
      });
    }


**MyController**
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class PatientController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("GetTestData")]
       //--These is the one i can't access
        public IActionResult GetTestData() 
        {
            return Ok("");
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("GetTestDataOne")]
        public IActionResult GetTestDataOne()
        {
            return Ok("Hi John");
        }
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.; Database=blah;persist security info=True;user id=blah;password=blah;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "Secret": "1234567890123456",
    "ClientURL": ""
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddDbContext<PPMPBookingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Secret"].ToString());

        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        //var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        //services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });


        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {

            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidIssuer="vlad",
                ValidAudience="Client"

            };
        });
        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddScoped<IPracticeService, PracticeService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

**AccountController**

```
public UserInfo Authenticate(int businessID, string username, string password)
        {

            // authentication successful so generate jwt token
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("ApplicationSettings:Secret").Value);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.ID.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            userInfo.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes($"{businessID}{username}");
            userInfo.AuthData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            user.Password = null;
            userInfo.User = user;
            userInfo.BusinessID = businessID;
            userInfo.Practice = _practiceService.PracticeInfo(businessID);
            userInfo.CurrentTabID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            return userInfo;
        }
```

Comment: Are you certain that the JWT is being sent correctly in the header? Code looks fine to me. I recently implemented this exact pattern and I had an issue where the JWT was getting generated for an anonymous user because the logic was running before the auth process had finished. This lead to the JWT in angular not matching the expected JWT back in the authroize process. So maybe check that as well?